# Variable does not exist in current context and invalid arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

[image]

I am trying to validate a text box.I have validated a couple of other text boxes and they work fine.This one has some error.
My code looks correct to me.Someone please point out my mistake and tell me why Visual Studio 2010 is prompting an error of invalid arguments and variable not in current context:

Comment: Read up on how to use `out`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: You have not declared errorMsg within the addTextBox_Validating method.  Your code is not right its just plain wrong.

Comment: You should first declare the out variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `string errorMsg;` in `addTextBox_Validating` function before you call `ValidAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the errorMsg variable before using it as an out parameter.

```
string errorMsg;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read up on how to use out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Although variables passed as an out arguments need not be initialized prior to being passed, the calling method is required to assign a value before the method returns.

```
class OutExample
{
    static void Method(out int i)
    {
        i = 44;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        int value;
        Method(out value);
        // value is now 44
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a string as second parameter to ValidAddress. Try and add

string errorMsg = null;

as first line of addTextBox_Validating()

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the errorMsg string.

```
private void addTextBox_Validating (object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    string errorMsg = "";
    ...etc

}
```

In ValidAddress, the errorMsg string is passed in to the function as a parameter, so this issue does not arise.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, errorMsg is not declared anywhere.

Try changing **addTextBox_Validating** by adding a declaration for it

e.g.

```
var errorMsg = string.Empty;

if (!ValidAddress(...
```

An out variable needs to be declared in the context that it is used.

hth 
Alan.

Answer (score -1):

Where is `errorMsg` defined? It looks like it's sent in as a parameter to `ValidAddress`, so `addTextBox_Validating`, being a different method entirely, doesn't have access to it, as `errorMsg` is scoped to only exist in `ValidAddress`. Long story short, you haven't initialised your variable.